# CSS drop down menu is not visible in DIV in IE7

Tags: css

here is the link showing the problem: http://www.ukrainetraveling.com.

The CSS drop down submenu is not visible. I've put z-index as "1" in all divs that are there, and "200" for one that has the menu, but no result.
in chrome it works as expected.

Could you please help me with that issue?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Helpful.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and its still not visible.

Comment: @jaredhoyt: It's a comment, and it's true.  Developing for IE7 means ignoring the last 10 years of internet standards.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: You're right. I had never realized IE7 sucked until you brought it to our attention. Thank you for the valuable input.

Comment: well, please try again in chrome - it should work, I just checked. Honestly, it is not developed for IE7, but it's only that I opened it in IE7 and it was not working. in IE8 - the same.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs IE8 was release in 2009... when doing actual client work IE7 support becomes an unfortunate but necessary task.

Comment: Sarcasm much?  It's a comment, not an answer, and completely appropriate.  If it bothers you so much, give an answer instead of commentary on my commentary... at least that's on subject.

Comment: @Kroehre, I did not imply that it was not necessary, but IE7 was based on standards available in 2004, the better part of a decade.  The fact is, supporting IE7 is his problem; not getting this one thing to work, because then it will be getting the next thing to work, and the next...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE7 is known to have problems stacking elements when using `position` and `z-index`. What you need to do is to tell the browser step by step what he should be doing.

**Try this:**

```
// menu
ul.pureCssMenu {
  position: relative;
}
```

**If not enough, you can:**

```
// parent of .pureCssMenu
div {
  position: relative;
}
```

---

**Note:**
Your menu as is does not work on IE8 or IE9 as well.

---

## EDITED

Just notice that your document does not contain a [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/Doctype), please refer to [this link](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) to set an appropriated document type.

This is an important factor since any browser needs to know how are you writing your code, and the DOCTYPE does just that, tells the browser "*I am written like this, so please use this specific set of rules to show me*".

Related to IE6, 7, 8, 9, etc... It enters on what they call "*compatibility mode*" that is the same as using the IE5 standards (way outdated). Refer to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx) for more information.

Comment: thanks for reply. I know it is not working in IE8 and 9. I tried your suggestion. "relative" in ul.purecssmenu - killed the formating in Chrome but no result in IE7. "relative" in div gave no result neither alone nor with the first suggestion. I left both changes - to be let anybody see the effect.

Comment: Ok, I'll setup a Fiddle with your current code to see whats the "real" problem there!